# Append dynamically built form element to my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have used jquery/javascript to dynamically build the form elements that I want. These include text and select fields. I would now like to append these elements to my form. Below is what I have tried.

Form:

```
<form id='associates' method="post">
<table border="1" id='mytable' ><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="<?php echo  csrf_token(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rowIDcount" id="rowIDcount" >
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var name="<input id='name"+x+"' readonly value='"+array3[i]['Assoc_Name']+"'>";
var form=document.getElementById('associates');
  form.appendChild(name);
```

There is obviously more javascript/jquery to build the name variable but that does not need posted.

How can I append name to my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need valid HTML, without unclosed tables and rows.

Secondly, you can't pass a string to `appendChild`.

As you've stated you're using jQuery, it should be straight forward

```
$('<input />', {
    name     : 'name' + x,
    readOnly : 'readonly',
    value    : array3[i]['Assoc_Name']
}).appendTo('#associates');
```

Comment: Sorry about the missing tags, I have them closed it just must not have copied over. So I have a loop that builds several of these inputs, would I just put the above code in that loop?

Comment: Sure, it should create the elements and append them. If you're creating lots of elements, storing them in a temporary container, then appending all at once, is generally a lot faster.